# How to show $I\cap J$ is in $I+J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I don't know how to show that $I\cap J$ is in $I+J$ where $I$ is a ideal of a ring $R$, and $J$ is a left ideal of $R$. It is easy to show that $IJ$ is in $I\cap J$, but it is hard to show first proposition. Can you help me? It is okay that you give only some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $I\cap J$ is a subset of $I$ and for $x\in I$ we have $x+0\in I+J$ since $0\in J$.

Comment: Oh... it was so simple.. haha^^ Thank you so much!!!